# Reemplazar valores vacíos en variable dicotómica SQL

Tags: sql

tengo una tabla de clientes, donde una columna es la variable Sexo (incluye masculino y femenino), de los cuales el 30% esta vacia, quiero reemplazar esos vacíos con Masculino y Femenino de forma proporcional a la tabla (0.7 masculino y 0.3 femenino), mi idea era utilizar como un comando aleatorio que coloque Masculino con probabilidad de éxito 0.7 y femenino con 0.3, no se si eso se pueda realizar en SQL Server, soy nuevo en este software.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos estás usando? En principio cada motor de BD tiene funcionalidades para usar PRNG... Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Sí se puede hacer, pero depende del motor de base de datos que estés usando.

Comment: Se puede realizar en cualquiera de los tres lenguajes que has especificado,  pero limita tu pregunta a una sola etiqueta, ¿lo quieres en SQL? en este caso es imprescindible que indiques el motor de base de datos como te han mencionado, por que la generación aleatoria no forma parte del estándar del lenguaje y cada base tiene su forma de resolverlo.

Comment: Creo que en muchas ocasiones se puede plantear la solucion al problema de una manera mas sencilla. que te parece si obtienes la cantidad de registros que tienen esa celda sin valor, calculas el 70 porciento y el 30 porciento, realizas un update del 70 % con el sexo = masculino con una consulta, y luego ejecutas otra consulta para el update con sexo = femenino del 30% restante. Saludos

Comment: @Daniel Me ha gustado tu propuesta, con tu permiso la implemento :)

Comment: por supuesto, es un placer. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta solución en MySQL para que busques cómo implementarla en SQL Server:

```
set @i:=0;
UPDATE clientes JOIN (
    SELECT @i:=@i+1 i,id_cliente,n,
      IF(@i<=n*.7,1,0) sexo
      FROM (
        SELECT id_cliente,(
           SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clientes
            WHERE sexo IS NULL       
          ) n FROM clientes
          WHERE sexo IS NULL
          ORDER BY RAND()
      ) clientes  
  ) c1 USING(id_cliente)
  set clientes.sexo=c1.sexo;
```

El dataset podría ser:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
  id_cliente int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cliente varchar(15),
  sexo bool
  );
INSERT INTO clientes (cliente) VALUES
  ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),
  ('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('0');
```

La codificación sería `sexo=1` para masculino y `sexo=0` para femenino. La probabilidad de sexo masculino la puedes modificar en el `.7` del `IF()`.

No es la solución, pero espero que te ayude a encontrarla.

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server te podría servir:

Supongamos tengas una tabla así:

```sql
create table clientes(id int, sexo varchar(20))
insert into clientes values(1, null),(2, null),(3, null),(4, null),
(5, null),(6, null),(7, null) 

-- table: 

+----+------+
| id | sexo |
+----+------+
| 1  | null |
| 2  | null |
| 3  | null |
| 4  | null |
| 5  | null |
| 6  | null |
| 7  | null |
+----+------+
```

Con dos UPDATE podrías tenerlo, lo fundamental aquí es tomar el 70% de todos los valores de la tabla, en este caso he colocado `NULL` en el `WHERE` para así simular a tú tabla real.

```sql
update clientes
set sexo = 'masculino'
where id = any ( select top 70 percent id 
                 from clientes
                 where sexo is null
                 order by newid() ) 

update clientes 
set sexo = 'fememnino'
where sexo is null
```

El último UPDATE se supone que afectará a los últimos registros que tengan NULL, ya que los demás estarán actualizados y por tanto NO VACÍOS ni NULOS.

> Una nota importante es que usando el `NEWID()` te tomará aleatoriamente los registros de la tabla clientes.

Finalmente, esta tabla de ejemplo podría quedar así, ya que, como dije, es aleatorio, así que el orden será distinto con toda seguridad, pero el porcentaje siempre se mantendrá (en este caso el 70% corresponde a 5 clientes):

```sql
+----+-----------+
| id | sexo      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | masculino |
| 2  | masculino |
| 3  | femenino  |
| 4  | masculino |
| 5  | femenino  |
| 6  | masculino |
| 7  | masculino |
+----+-----------+
```